# How to bind <Control><Arrowkey> in Mutt?

Tags: mutt

I’m stuck here:

Is it possible to bind one of `<enter>, <backspace>, <up>, <down>, <left>, <right>` together with control?

`\C<foo>` shows up as `|foo>` in the help and `^<up>` isn’t bound.
`'\C<foo>`, `'\C <foo>'` don’t work, too (same with `"` instead).

`<control>` doesn’t exist.

You actually *can* get `^<foo>` to show up in the help, but only if you map `^<foo>`, which isn’t exactly what I want. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to determine whether your terminal sends different escape sequences for these key combinations. Applications running in terminals get characters as input, not keys. Function keys are encoded as control characters or as escape sequences beginning with the escape character (which you can write as `\e` in a key binding).

To see the escape sequence sent by a key combination in a terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> at a shell prompt, then press the key combination. For example, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> at a shell prompt, I see `^[O5D`. `^[` is the escape character, so I would need to bind `\eO5D` in Mutt to make it react to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>:

```
bind editor \eO5D backward-word
```

Some terminals send the same escape sequence for the same key with different modifiers. If that's the case, you'll need to figure out how to change the terminal's behavior or switch to a different terminal.

Comment: Sounds good, but it doesn’t work. `\e` is the escape key, not the escape character…

Comment: @Profpatsch Weird, that binding works for me. I've been using Mutt 1.5 since about forever, maybe 1.4 works differently? Does it work if you use `\e` in a macro: `macro editor \e[O5D \eb`?

Comment: I’m on Terminator, when I hit `Ctrl+Down` I get `^[[1;5B`, it doesn’t work with `bind index \e[1;5B command` and not with `\e1;5B `, too. Oh, I work with Mutt 1.5.21 (Arch. ;)

Comment: @Profpatsch Ok, I can reproduce this. There seems to be a limitation to 5 characters: `bind editor \e[1\;5 backward-word` works for me (and inserts an extra `D` when I enter `ESC [ 1 ; 5 D`), but `bind editor \e[1\;5D backward-word` results in `ESC [ 1 ; 5 D` doing nothing. I see a limitation to 8 characters in the source code (`MAX_SEQ`), but nothing that would trigger at 5 characters.

Comment: @Profpatsch A workaround would be to make your terminal send shorter sequences. I don't know if Terminator supports this.

Comment: @Gilles, Just for the reference, In Mutt 1.10.1, both `bind editor \e[1\;9D backward-word` and `bind editor \e[1\;9C forward-word` do work.

Comment: Any idea what pre-sequence to press on macOS Terminal.app?

Answer (score 22):

I found the correct answer here: [Bind ctrl+up in muttrc | mail-archive.com](https://www.mail-archive.com/mutt-users@mutt.org/msg36980.html).

Inside mutt, use the command

```
:exec what-key
```

Then pressing the desired key (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd>) you can learn how to reference any key.  In my case I get `<C-Up>` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>.

Hit `Ctrl-g` to exit what-key.

Comment: In case you succeeded in using `:exec what-key` to get this information, but then could not figure out "what-key" to press to get out of the `what-key` command, the key sequence to exit is `Ctrl-g`.

Comment: In any terminal/config where I tried that (with NeoMutt 20191207 or Mutt 1.13.2) `what-key` just give me a letter `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`.

I am not the only one : https://www.mail-archive.com/mutt-users@mutt.org/msg36985.html